# How can connect hive metastore in a database or save in a volume in bitnami spark container?

Tags: docker, apache-spark, bitnami, hive-metastore

`Bitnami/spark` has build in `hive metastore` , but the data of that is saved in container. How we can use database to save `hive metastore` or set `volume` for it `metastore_db`?